# How to create hybrith route like (Pedestrian and Car)?

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps

I have a route that includes vehicle and pedestrian mode together. When HERE is creating this, I want to show the pedestrian parts with dashed lines or different color for users to understand.

I parsed routes sections for sectionTransportMode like that

```
    _routeCalculator.calculatePedestrianRoute(waypoints, (HERE.RoutingError? routingError, List<HERE.Route>? routeList) async {
      if (routingError == null) {
        HERE.Route _calculatedRoute = routeList!.first;

        _calculatedRoute.sections.forEach((element) {
          print('TransportMode: ' + element.sectionTransportMode.toString());

        });

        _showRouteOnMap(_calculatedRoute);
        _startNavigationOnRoute(isSimulated, _calculatedRoute);
      } else {
        final error = routingError.toString();
        _showDialog('Error', 'Error while calculating a pedestrian route: $error');
      }
    });
```

But how can i do that after this code snippet.

Comment: Can you confirm that you get different transport modes when you print it out? My experience is that multi-modal routing is not yet supported and the car route will stop when a pedestrian part is required. For example, when user's destination and route destination do not match, calculate another route with pedestrian transport mode, then you can easily print that route in a different color.

Comment: PS: If I recall correctly, only "ferries" can show up as a transport mode that may differ along the route's sections.

Comment: How can i know user's destination and route destination do not match sitiation? @Datasun

Comment: You can compare the last coordinate of the route polyline with the coordinate of the destination waypoint you have used for route calculation. If the distance between both coordinates is large enough you can decide if this is worth to calculate a pedestrian route between both coordinates ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MapPolyline consists of three elements:

1. A list of two or more geographic coordinates that define where to place the polyline on the map.
2. A GeoPolyline that contains this list of coordinates.
3. Style parameters such as **DashPattern** or **LineCap** to define how to visualize the polyline.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.8.3.0/dev_guide/topics/map-items.html#add-map-polylines

When calling the showRouteOnMap, you can create the MapPolyline with dashed lines as shown below in the example.

Here is an example:

```
private void showRouteOnMap(Route route) {
        // Show route as polyline.
        GeoPolyline routeGeoPolyline;
        try {
            routeGeoPolyline = new GeoPolyline(route.getPolyline());
        } catch (InstantiationErrorException e) {
            // It should never happen that a route polyline contains less than two vertices.
            return;
        }

        float widthInPixels = 20;

        //Blue Color
        //Color lineColor = Color.valueOf(0, 0f, 0f, 139f);

        MapPolyline routeMapPolyline = new MapPolyline(routeGeoPolyline,
                widthInPixels,
                Color.valueOf(0, 0.56f, 0.54f, 0.63f)); // RGBA
        //Setting polyline to DashPattern
        routeMapPolyline.setDashPattern(new DashPattern(10));
       // routeMapPolyline.setDashFillColor(lineColor);

        mapView.getMapScene().addMapPolyline(routeMapPolyline);
        mapPolylines.add(routeMapPolyline);

        // Draw a circle to indicate starting point and destination.
        addCircleMapMarker(startGeoCoordinates, R.drawable.green_dot);
        addCircleMapMarker(destinationGeoCoordinates, R.drawable.green_dot);

        // Log maneuver instructions per route section.
        List<Section> sections = route.getSections();
        for (Section section : sections) {
            logManeuverInstructions(section);
        }
    }
```

Please refer to this example available in git:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/routing_hybrid_app

Comment: Here is the flutter code;

    double widthInPixels = 20;
    MapPolyline routeMapPolyline = MapPolyline(routeGeoPolyline, widthInPixels, Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0));
    routeMapPolyline.outlineWidth = 5;
    routeMapPolyline.dashPattern = DashPattern(10, 12);